# create interface of specific options (rating interface, allow only numbers between 1-5)

Tags: angular, typescript, types, interface, angular-cli

I want to create `oneToFive` interface that allows only numbers between 1-5.

How do you write this in a correct way?

```
// this line gives me error
interface oneToFive = 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5;

interface sectionFeedback {
  howMuchDoYouRelate?: oneToFive;
  howWellWasThisTextWritten?: oneToFive;
}
```

Comment: Use `type oneToFive = 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5;`

Comment: I would mark your question as correct :) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `type` instead of `interface`

```
type oneToFive = 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5;
```

Thank you for your answer! @Heretic Monkey